# Get image from Database as you scroll (HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, database

I want to create an Image Gallery, with the images stored on the database.
say i display 9 images on the page, and as i scroll down, the next 9 images are displayed or appends to the current 9. How can i do it with ajax and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In client:

```
<ul id="images">
    <li><img src="img/test1.jpg" id="1" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/test2.jpg" id="2"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/test3.jpg" id="3" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/test4.jpg" id="4"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/test5.jpg" id="5"/></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var last_image_id = $('ul#images li:last-child').attr('id');

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'loadimage.php/last_id='last_image_id,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('ul#images').append(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    }

</script>
```

and in server side:

```
<?php
// connect to db
$query = 'select form image_table where id > '.$_GET['last_id'].' LIMIT 9';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<li><img src="'.$row->image.'" alt=""></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: whatever the php echo is what the jquery '.done(function(data)' gets?

Comment: @RiverCRPhoenix jquery .done(data) gets result of php page and sets in data paramter

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have a look at a lazy loading plugin like [this one](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: tried with lazy load, but didnt work the way i wanted.